# How many 10s are present here?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You might get a couple of different answers for the following:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I count

> 7

> Hidden as either TEN, 10 or IO 
>  [image: answer]

Comment: I would have liked the question better if O was more ambiguous, but I like this answer regardless.

Answer (score 3):

I got

> either 8 or 10

> [image: answer version 1]
>
>  using the vertical line in the H as a 1

> [image]
>
>  This one might be a bit of a stretch, but A in hexadecimal is 10, plus having ten 10s seems fitting

Answer (score 1):

When this question is read out loud, ten is mentioned 6 times. 5 of them individually except for ten in senTENce. If you are doing it by looking at the piece of text, it is 7(the billion). Otherwise, if you are counting the number 10(as a number not in other words) its 5.